# Keyboard volume hotkey lag

Tags: keyboard, 14.10, volume-control

After I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.10 i got problems with my <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> (they are my volume hotkeys.). Sometimes when I press them there is a large lag 10sec to 1min, and some times they respond immediately. There may also be problems with other hotkes but I am not sure.

Comment: I have the same problem, I tried to narrow down the issue with these instructions https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Hotkeys/Troubleshooting and now I just opened a bug report for it https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1435108 I don't think this will be really useful, though...